# Options to start timelapse sequence in the morning and stop in the evening, then repeat on Pi Cam Web UI?

Tags: raspbian, raspicam

Hi all I've been using Pi Cam with Web UI on RPi3 (with naturebytes build) for a long term timelapse (9 months). I've been successfully shoot timelapse for the past week but it shoots the whole day night cycle but I only want the day time photos. What I've been doing is press stop on the UI every evening and wake up to push start timelapse again. Is there anyway to automate this process? Or an option for time based operational like not shooting after 5 pm or something.

In any case if there's no easy way to do it I'm game with a way to automate trashing all the night image afterwards.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't know how the web ui starts / stops the timelapse, but you could have a look at sunwait (linux program) or the python module 'ephem'

Answer (score 1):

If there's a "command line version" of the timelapse program you're using, or if you can control it from (for example) a `bash` or `Python` script, `cron` should be able to do what you want. In fact you ***may*** be able to run a "gui program" from `cron`, but I've never tried that.

Generically, the approach is this:

1. create an entry in `crontab` to start your program in the morning (whenever)
2. create a second entry to halt the program in the evening (whenever)

Suggest you read `man cron`, `man crontab` and Google a bit to familiarize yourself with it. Then schedule a few simple `cron` jobs to gain familiarity. Let us know if you hit a snag; specific questions are best.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Here is the software I use.I will check those out. I'm quite new to this and naturebytes is flash and work out of the box. However, when I want to customize it I can't do anything bec6i know nothing. Thank you will get started reading.

Comment: Link https://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface

Comment: @DhanusSamsen: You said, "... i know nothing." We all began knowing nothing, and so it is with you also - welcome to the club!! But know this: you will only learn by digging, trying and failing. And so after you read of `cron` and how it works, you should also review [this link. It implies that the scheduling function you need is already built in to the web interface.](https://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface#Scheduler). If this addresses your question, please let me know.

Comment: I read the scheduling page three times already and I still don't get it. Looks like it's so flexible I don't know what to change. What do you think I should know before I can grasp on it?

Comment: I don't get it either... it's not the clearest thing I've ever seen. There was a link to another Q&A website that seems to be dedicated to this tool. They would probably be able to offer more help as they "specialize" in that. Here's the link:(https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=63276)

Comment: Here's a [link that may help](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2016/15/Using-the-RPi-Cam-Web-Interface)